# Получение цвета на координатах экрана Python

Tags: python

Мне нужно получить цвет пикселя на экране по двум координатам. Есть ли какое-то решение для этого?

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Color_of_a_screen_pixel#Python

Comment: Можно проще https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для windows:

```
import win32gui


def get_pixel_colour(i_x, i_y):
    i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    i_desktop_window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(i_desktop_window_id)
    long_colour = win32gui.GetPixel(i_desktop_window_dc, i_x, i_y)
    i_colour = int(long_colour)
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(i_desktop_window_id,i_desktop_window_dc)
    return (i_colour & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 8) & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 16) & 0xff)


print (get_pixel_colour(0, 0))
```